# FIPS compliance for .NET Framework

Tags: .net

I’ve been investigating how to achieve FIPS compliance for .Net Framework 4.8 nowadays and I’d like to confirm some of my findings. Please, correct me if I’m wrong:

1. **Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider** is no longer FIPS compliant, as the certification for the underlying implementation (`rsaenh.dll`) is now historical: https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/certificate/1894
2. Using AES by calling `AES.Create` is not FIPS-compliant as it would use `AesCryptoServiceProvider`, which uses **Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider**. The correct way is to use `new AesCng` as it uses a FIPS-compliant implementation (bcryptprimitives.dll), which as an active NIST certification: https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/certificate/4536
3. When using `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`, I can still achieve FIPS compliance by using a smart card and passing `csp` parameters pointing to the smart card. That’s not true with `AesCryptoServiceProvider` because it does not accept custom `csp` parameters.

One question I have in mind, which is perhaps wishful thinking, is if using **Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider** nowadays actually redirects to use something that is FIPS compliant, such as `bcryptprimitives`. Is that the case, or am I indeed not FIPS compliant when using Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider and should migrate to CNG implementations instead?

Thank you.

Comment: Not an answer hers though some information.  Seems that FIPS is not a focus for Microsoft anymore.  More info. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1188777/fips-for-windows-11 and https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-security-baselines/why-we-re-not-recommending-fips-mode-anymore/ba-p/701037 and  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/fips-compliance

Comment: It was when we were looking for a pure .net solution to FIPS compliance and not a reliance on a Win32 codec.  Basically, you had to reset the machine Windows setting to downgrade to FIPS compliance and run with that.  Not a good solution.

Comment: Azure supposedly supports it so Microsoft maybe still working on FIPS compliance. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/compliance/offerings/offering-fips-140-2#azure-and-fips-140

Comment: Have you looked at [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/fips-csharp/)